# Core Data saving problem: can't update transformable attribute (NSArray)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a strange problem in my Core Data app.

I have three entities in my app, but today I found a problem with one of them. My problematic entity is called `Invoice` and it has many attributes, including `Products`. It's encoded NSArray of NSDictionaries (via default NSValueTransformer).

Everything works fine - i create my invoice, its client, its products, etc. Everything works.

**But**, when I choose my invoice from a list and then try to edit its products and click 'Save' button, my save works only until my app gets terminated.

The problem is only with my `products` array - the rest (e.g. payment date, client etc.) saves.

---

**What am I doing**

I pass my `Invoice` object via

```
NSManagedObject *inv = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
invoiceEditor.invoice = inv;
```

And save my data (in my `InvoiceEditor` VC):

```
[self.invoice setValue:client forKey:@"Client"] // NSDictionary;
[self.invoice setValue:products forKey:@"Products"] // NSArray of NSDictionaries;
[self.invoice setValue:pmDate forKey:@"PaymentDate"] // NSDate;
// other attributes
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.invoice.managedObjectContext;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Everythings saves until being terminated: client, products, dates. But only products are 'reseted' after termination.

Anybody?

Comment: Clarification: What do you mean by " products are 'reseted'"? Do you mean that the product attribute is not saved? Do you mean it reverts to a previous value? In other words, what do ***expect*** to see for the `products` attribute after restart and what do you ***actually*** see?

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using a entity and a relationship instead of a bunch of NSDictionary objects inside a NSArray? That is a very cumbersome and (most likely) slow setup.

Comment: 1. I mean that products attribute is saved but after my app gets terminated it returns to previous value. 2. I don,t use relationship because I need the products all the time, even if user has deleted them. I have an entity called 'Product' but in my 'Invoice' I'm storing its copy.

Comment: The problem would have to be in the transformer or the Invoice class. Are you using a custom transformer? If so, post the code. If not, what does the Invoice class accessor for the `product` attribute look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the problem. From [Model Object Implementation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/Articles/moBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002134-SW3):

> If there are mutable and immutable versions of a class you use to represent a property—such as NSArray and NSMutableArray—you should typically declare the return value of the get accessor as an immutable object even if internally the model uses a mutable object.

And my `products` array was actually a **`NSMutableArray`** instance. I solved it by copying `products` (so I converted mutable array to immutable array). Now it works. :) And I didn't need to start the bounty...

Comment: I'm wracking my brains as to what crazy kind of implementation detail would lead to the effect you're seeing. Why should the behaviour be any different for a mutable array, which is polymorphic to an immutable one, and therefore requires particular action to be taken to be distinguished at runtime? And even more intriguing -- why is transience the upshot?!

Comment: I don't know why is that. And I don't care, my app just works! :P

Comment: I guess there are two kinds of programmer in this world: those who just want their code to work and those who want to understand why it does.

Comment: Yep, but there are things that we, programmers, are not supposed to understand, I think... Some axioms...

Comment: that documentation doesn't say you need to convert it to a non-mutable type, it just says you should _declare_ it as a non-mutable type (a good general rule to follow most of the time)  (.h = declare, .m = define)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you've just found the problem. Sorry I just read your problem, but CoreData has several problems during saving.

Each attribute in a CoreData Entity must be immutable objects.