# Magical Record appears to save, but changes are lost if app is terminated

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1

I'm using Magical Record 2.1 to handle the data persistence in my app. If I create a new entity, set some it's attributes and save, it works fine. However, later, if I fetch that entity, update it's attributes and save, subsequent fetches have the new data until I terminate the app and restart. During the new app session the old data reappears.

This is how I create a new entity:

```
self.localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
self.theNewListing = [Listing MR_createInContext:self.localContext];
```

I'm using MRDefaultContext having read this blog post: http://saulmora.com/2013/09/15/why-contextforcurrentthread-doesn-t-work-in-magicalrecord/

In this case my main attribute is a dictionary, and I set it like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A description", @"slFieldDescription", etc, etc, nil];
self.theNewListing.dataDictionary = tempDictionary;
```

This is how I save it:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {

    [self.localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
        if(!success) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
        else {
            [self.thePresentingVC refreshCollectionViews:nil];
        }
    }];
}];
```

I display my data in a collection view, and at this point everything looks fine. If I terminate and restart the data is still there.

If I fetch the entity again and update the attributes like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newTempDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A new description", @"slFieldDescription", etc, etc, nil];
self.theNewListing.dataDictionary = newTempDictionary;
```

Then save using the same save code as above, and then update my collection view using the code below, all looks good.

```
self.listingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[Listing MR_findAllSortedBy:@"dateListed" ascending:NO]];
[self.mainCollectionView reloadData];
```

That is, until I quit the app and restart.

If you're wondering, I'm using FTASync, and this only supports MR 2.1, which is why I haven't upgraded to the latest version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it!!

I noticed that my other attributes were saving, just not this one (this one holds all the data that is presented in the UI) and this led me on another line of investigation.

So, it seems that I needed to be working with immutable dictionaries to store this data as explained here:

[Core Data saving problem: can't update transformable attribute (NSArray)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596869/core-data-saving-problem-cant-update-transformable-attribute-nsarray)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MR, nor why you would need it. If that framework can give you the main context, just call the native Core Data save.

```
[context save:nil];
```

Comment: MR is great when it works! It saves a lot of time. Also, I am also using FTASync which requires MR. I tried adding in the core data save after the MR save as a test, but still no luck.